# .Net with MySQL: ignore parameters in commandtext

Tags: mysql, vb.net, parameters

I'm trying to copy some stored procedures from one server to another server.  Mostly it works fine, but I have some SPs, where @max_heap_table_size is defined. The .Net connector then refuses to work with the error "Parameter '@max_heap_table_size' must be defined.". How can I manage the command not to use parameters?

A part of the code (scom is the source-command, tcom is the target-command):

```
scom.CommandText = "show create procedure `" & proc & "`"
rd = scom.ExecuteReader
If rd.Read() Then
    Dim cmd As String = "delimiter $$" & Environment.NewLine & rd.GetString(2) & "$$" & Environment.NewLine & "delimiter ;"
    tcom.CommandText = cmd
    tcom.ExecuteNonQuery()
End If
```

There is no problem with users and privileges. Some SPs are copied this way without any problems. But the SPs that uses global MySQL-variables can't be copied this way.

Thank you!

Edit: question is tagged as VB.net and C#, because it is independent of the .Net language.

Edit2: proc is the name of the stored procedure, rd.GetString(2) returns the "show create procedure" (see first two lines of the code). It is returned from MySQL in column index 2.

Comment: Without knowing what is the value of _proc_ and what is the return value of _rd.GetString(2)_ it is pretty impossible to say what happens here. A part from this I think that reader doesn't return what you expect

Comment: Sorry, I will edit the question to be more clear.

Comment: It sounds like @max_heap_table_size is being interpreted as a command parameter, not as part of the procedure. Do any of the procedures that work have parameters?

Comment: @crowcoder yes, this is my problem. It is part of the procedure-text, not a parameter. There are no parameters.

Comment: Please give the reason for -1.

Comment: You will need to find a tool other than ADO.Net, I don't know what tools exist for MySQL but I would use SMO or sqlcmd in MSSQL for this operation.

Answer (score 0):

You will find your answer here. You should use a double @@. Also make sure you use MySQL .NET connector that comes with MySQL.

[max heap set](https://dicortazar.wordpress.com/2010/07/09/changing-your-max_heap_table_size-variable/)

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the answer. The question was, how to tell the .Net MySQLCommand not to parse the command text for parameters.

Comment: you want to access max_heap_table_size you should use @@max_heap_table_size and not @max_heap_table_size